# Codeigniter Call to a member function result() on a non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

I have this code:

```
public function getJccLineItem($id,$action)
{
    $res = array();
    $q = 'SELECT * FROM jcc_line_items jli,ipo_line_item ili ,line_items li
        WHERE jli.line_item_id= ili.id and li.id = jli.line_item_id
        and ili.dn_number_id in ( Select dn_number from ipo where project_id= '.$id.')';
    $res = $this->db->query($q);
    echo $this->db->last_query();
    $jccLineItemArray = array();
    echo $id;
    print_r($res->result());

    if($action == 'array')
    {

        foreach ( $res->result() as $key => $value) // The error comes in this line
        {
            $jccLineItemArray[ $value->id ] = $value->item_description;
        }
        $res = $jccLineItemArray;


    }  
    else 
    {

        $res = $res->result();
    }

    return $res;
}
```

The error is in the foreach loop. I have printed the result and it shows the result in object array but when it goes to foreach loop. It show this error

> **"Call to a member function result() on a non-object "**

But when I set `db['default']['db_debug']=true` , it shows that the `$id` is missing from the query whereas when it was false it was showing result in object array and giving error at loop. Any Help would be appreciated.Thanks

Controller Code

```
public function createInvoice( $id = "" ) 
{        
    if (empty($id)) 
    {
        $id = $this->input->post('dataid');
    }
    echo $id;
    $data['jcc_line_list'] = $this->product_model->getJccLineItem($id,'array');
    $data['jcc_line_lists'] = $this->product_model->getJccLineItem($id,'');
    $data['items'] = $this->product_model->getAllSubInvoice($id);
    $data['single_project'] = $this->product_model->getSingleProject($id);
    $data['site'] = $this->product_model->getAllSiteArray();
    $data['job_types'] = $this->product_model->getAllJobTypeArray();
    $data['title'] = 'Invoice';
    $data['operation'] = 'Create';
    $data['buttonText'] = 'Save';
    $data['id'] = $id;
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->helper('security');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('line_item_id', 'Line Item', 'required|xss_clean|max_length[50]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('job_type_id', 'Job Type', 'required|xss_clean|max_length[50]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('site_id', 'Site', 'required|xss_clean|max_length[50]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('milestone', 'Milestone', 'required|xss_clean|max_length[50]');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<span class="error">', '</span>');


    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error_message', validation_errors());
        $this->load->view('admin/viewinvoicesub', $data);
    } else if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {

        $formData = array(
            'invoice_id' => $id,
            'line_item_id' => $this->form_validation->set_value('line_item_id'),
            'job_type_id' => $this->form_validation->set_value('job_type_id'),
            'site_id' => $this->form_validation->set_value('site_id'),
            'milestone' => $this->form_validation->set_value('milestone'),
        );
        $this->product_model->insertInvoiceSub($formData);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('sucess_message', "Data successfully save !");
        redirect('Products/createInvoice', "refresh");
    } else {
        $this->load->view('admin/viewinvoicesub', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: first assign `$res->result()` to a variable and then use that variable in `foreach` loop

Comment: nothing happens.same result

Comment: @Umerm can you tell me what was the issue  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this and let me know if that helps

```
public function getJccLineItem($id = '' ,$action = '')
{
    if($id != '')
    {
        $res = array();
        $q = 'SELECT * FROM jcc_line_items jli,ipo_line_item ili ,line_items li
            WHERE jli.line_item_id= ili.id and li.id = jli.line_item_id
            and ili.dn_number_id in ( Select dn_number from ipo where project_id= '.$id.')';
        $res = $this->db->query($q)->result();
        $jccLineItemArray = array();
        if($action == 'array')
        {
            foreach($res as $key => $value) // The error comes in this line
            {
                $jccLineItemArray[ $value->id ] = $value->item_description;
            }
            $res = $jccLineItemArray;
        }
        return $res;
    }
    else
    {
    echo "id is null"; die();
    }
}
```

And your Controller code should be

```
public function createInvoice( $id = "" ) 
{
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->helper('security'); 
    if ($id = "") 
    {
        $id = (isset($this->input->post('dataid')))?$this->input->post('dataid'):3;// i am sure your error is from here
    }   
    $data['jcc_line_list'] = $this->product_model->getJccLineItem($id,'array');
    $data['jcc_line_lists'] = $this->product_model->getJccLineItem($id,'');
    $data['items'] = $this->product_model->getAllSubInvoice($id);
    $data['single_project'] = $this->product_model->getSingleProject($id);
    $data['site'] = $this->product_model->getAllSiteArray();
    $data['job_types'] = $this->product_model->getAllJobTypeArray();
    $data['title'] = 'Invoice';
    $data['operation'] = 'Create';
    $data['buttonText'] = 'Save';
    $data['id'] = $id;
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {   
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('line_item_id', 'Line Item', 'required|xss_clean|max_length[50]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('job_type_id', 'Job Type', 'required|xss_clean|max_length[50]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('site_id', 'Site', 'required|xss_clean|max_length[50]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('milestone', 'Milestone', 'required|xss_clean|max_length[50]');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<span class="error">', '</span>');


        if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) 
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error_message', validation_errors());
            $this->load->view('admin/viewinvoicesub', $data);
        } 
        else
        {
            $formData = array(
                'invoice_id' => $id,
                'line_item_id' => $this->form_validation->set_value('line_item_id'),
                'job_type_id' => $this->form_validation->set_value('job_type_id'),
                'site_id' => $this->form_validation->set_value('site_id'),
                'milestone' => $this->form_validation->set_value('milestone'),
            );
            $this->product_model->insertInvoiceSub($formData);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('sucess_message', "Data successfully save !");
            redirect('Products/createInvoice/'.$id, "refresh");
        }
    }   
    else 
    {
        $this->load->view('admin/viewinvoicesub', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Edited now check again what is the output ?

Comment: And tell me how are you accessing **getJccLineItem('some_id','array')** ?

Comment: It is showing ID is null. But I have passed the id from controller method and it is displaying id there but it is not displaying in model method .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103363/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-umerm).

Comment: @devpro Thanks bro... but can't figure out what was the issue though. can you take a look ?   :)

Comment: Did a change in redirect added $id at last... **redirect('Products/createInvoice/'.$id, "refresh");**

Comment: @PraveenKumar - 'Continue this discussion in chat' doesn't help the rest of us who have come here.